# printing lines from multiple files

Tags: ifstream, getline

Im trying to print the first line from each file, then the second line from each file and so on.
When getline = EOF, then that file is closed and filesAreOpen is decremented, though the program loops forever

```
void PrintLines(ifstream files[], size_t count)
{
    string s;   
    ifstream *end, *start;
    int filesAreOpen = count;

    //continue while filesAreOpen > 0
    while(filesAreOpen)
    {

    }    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check with eof()? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/eof/

Comment: check where?, I do when trying to read in a line, and close the file if EOF

Comment: I didn't write C for a while. But something like the following should work start->is_open() && ! start->eof() . You may rewrite your code a bit. getline return istream http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ . It will never == EOF, though getline(*start, s).eof() might work. I hope it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to close files if EOF is reached. That will make your code much slower and painful to manage. Because you have to check if it is open, which involves file names. In this case, files are already open and you will read first line from each file than second line from each file and so on. But if a file reaches EOF, then of course you will miss that file and continue to read lines from other files. Until all files are reached EOF. Then close them all.

```
void PrintLines(ifstream files[], size_t count)
{

    int filesAreOpen = count;
    char line[250];

    //continue while filesAreOpen > 0
    while(filesAreOpen)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
      {
        if (!infile[i].eof())       
        {
          infile[i].getline(line,250);
          cout << line;
        }
            else
          filesAreOpen--;
      }
    }
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
      files[i].close();
}
```